# Scroll bars not working correctly with canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

The scroll bars move the canvas but they always snap back to the  top or the left.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame = Tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
canvas = Tk.Canvas(frame)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
scroll_x = Tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
scroll_y = Tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
canvas.create_oval(0,0,1333,1000)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The Canvas and Scrollbars have to be told about each other; you only did half the job.  Add `canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)` (this can be combined with the `.configure()` where you set the scrollregion).

Comment: @Rory: scrollbars shouldn't be placed in the widgets they are controlling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollbars require two-way communication with the widgets they are controlling. You've properly configured the scrollbars but haven't configured the canvas to update the scrollbars.

To do that, add the following code after you've defined the canvas and scrollbars:

```
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why scrollbars need a two way communication?

Comment: I know that they need it but what is the background of it? When I started with Tkinter long time ago (not that long like you though:) I was confused about this two-way concept. I thought that setting the command as **command=canvas.xview** in tk.Scrollbar does use the size data of the Canvas itself, which is not the case.

Comment: @Module_art: there are more ways to scroll a widget than with the scrollbar. The widget needs to know that there are scrollbars controlling it so that it can update the scrollbar to reflect the current state of the widget.

Comment: Thank you. It appears to work perfectly. I don't know how I missed that.